# mismatched input 'Not' expecting THEN in phase

Tags: sql, dql

I am getting an error on below query. Can someone suggest.

```
select Defects_1.id,
case when Defects_1.status Not Like '4-Closed%' then (CURRENTDATE() - Defects_1.creation_time) As Defect_Age end
case when Defects_1.status Like '4-Closed%' then Defects_1.user_11as Defect_Age end
from Defects_1
Order By Defects_1.id
```

Error :

> mismatched input 'Not' expecting THEN in phase PARSER at line 2,
>   column 27 for query

Comment: If this is anything like MSSQL, then you need to place your field aliases outside of your `CASE..WHEN..THEN..END` statement: `case when Defects_1.status Not Like '4-Closed%' then (CURRENTDATE() - Defects_1.creation_time) end As Defect_Age` and 
`case when Defects_1.status Like '4-Closed%' then Defects_1.user_11 end as Defect_Age`. You also don't have a space between `Defects_1.user_11` and `as Defect_Age` on the third line, which is likely a problem too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have some column like **Defects_1.closing_time** and this is what you intended -

```
select      Defects_1.id

           ,    case 
                    when Defects_1.status Not Like '4-Closed%' 
                    then CURRENTDATE()
                    else Defects_1.closing_time
                end 
            -   Defects_1.creation_time   As Defect_Age 

           ,case 

from        Defects_1

Order By    Defects_1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you intend a single `case` statement:

```
select Defects_1.id,
       (case when Defects_1.status Not Like '4-Closed%'
             then (CURRENTDATE() - Defects_1.creation_time)
             when Defects_1.status Like '4-Closed%'
             then Defects_1.user_11
         end) as Defect_Age
from Defects_1
Order By Defects_1.id
```

Comment: My original query was in DQL. I converted it into SQL, but now i am getting ORA-00936 missing expression error.
SQL query is

select BUG.BG_BUG_ID,
       (case when BUG.BG_STATUS Not Like '4-Closed%'
             then (DATE() - BUG.BG_DETECTION_DATE)
             when BUG.BG_STATUS Like '4-Closed%'
             then BUG.BG_USER_11
         end) as Defect_Age
from BUG
Order By BUG.BG_BUG_ID

Comment: If you are using Oracle, perhaps you intend `CURRENT_DATE` or `sysdate` instead of `CURRENTDATE()`.